# ERROR in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/table.vue

Tags: vue.js, babel-loader

I am getting error while loading vue components from same folder in vuejs.I have imported correctly. But while building ,it shows the below error.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/table.vue.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'features' in '/home/deploy/workspace/4url/static/shortening_url/src/components'
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/table.vue 67:0-32
 @ ./src/components/table.vue
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/main.js
```

Comment: What are you using to build? You've probably got a relative path incorrect in `./src/components/table.vue`

Answer (score 1):

We're going to need to see a little bit more of your code to properly help you, but my guess is that you did something like..

```js
import Features from "features";
```

instead of..

```js
import Features from "./features";
```

Which means that it's going to look in your `node_modules` folder instead of wherever that file is placed.

Answer (score 1):

**Try to check the import in App.vue**

Your import path is not correct that's why it shows the error

```
import showQoute from './components/showQoute/showQuote.vue'
```

*istead of*

```
import showQoute from './components/showQuote.vue'
```

.